# Table View rotate, but not properly (shape change)

Tags: iphone, uitableview, rotation, tableview

Here is the thing. I have a ViewController which contain a view in full window. And the program run in landscape mode.
  I want to put an UITableView over the full screen view but only on right half part of the screen.
  So I add a UITableView in my view controller, I used the Interface Builder in order to set the Table View in the upper half of the screen so It will be on the right part in LandscapeLeft mode.

I searched for on a lot of forum how to rotate my Table View. And so it does... except, It get stuck on the upper half of the landscape mode, it should stick on the right half.

I'm not a iPhone coder since long, so I'm a bit confused on how to solve this problem. Do you have any idea on how to resize or make the TableView rotate properly.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaViewsGuide/WorkingWithAViewHierarchy/WorkingWithAViewHierarchy.html), and focus the section Autoresizing of Subviews

You can do this graphically in IB and as well as in code!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for that link... I wish I found it before posting here.
 The view hierarchy is more clear to me now. I'll try to change my code using those new informations.